# I don't get operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
struct nodo{
    int v,k,dist;

    nodo(){
    }

    nodo(int _v, int _k, int _dist){
        v=_v;
        k=_k;
        dist=_dist;
    }

    bool operator < (nodo X) const{
        return dist>X.dist;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand this code. but i don't get bool operator part.

what does mean by "return dist>X.dist"?
If dist is bigger than X.dist, return true?

Comment: It's a convenience or "syntactic sugar" to be able to write `nodeA < nodeB` instead of `nodeA.dist > nodeB.dist`. That's what overloading operators is good for. It's an infix function notation for `nodeA.operator<(nodeB)` like you'd call any other member function.

Comment: What terrible book or tutorial are you using that doesn't even try to explain operator overloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what does mean by "return dist>X.dist"? If dist is bigger than X.dist, return true?

You're right.

Operators aren't different from a normal member function. The compiler just execute the function when finds that operator.

You could try put an print statement and see what happens

```
bool operator < (nodo X) const{
    std::cout << "Operator < called" << std::endl;
    return dist < X.dist; // I changed the sign because it looks more natural
}

// ...

int main() {
    nodo smallnode(1,2,3);
    nodo bignode(4,5,6);
    std::cout << "First node Vs Second Node" << std::endl;
    if (smallnode < bignode)
       std::cout << "It's smaller!" << std::endl;
    else
       std::cout << "It's bigger!" << std::endl;
}
```